# Minecraft: Fall Damage

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How many blocks does a Skeleton and Creeper need to fall to completely die? I've tried to do 24 blocks and it worked but it seems not necessary.

Comment: 23 blocks deals 10 hearts, so it is the minimum value for a mob to die

Answer (score 2):

From the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Damage#Fall_damage)

> Players receive damage when falling from excessive heights. Armour does not reduce fall damage, unless it is enchanted with Feather Falling or Protection. Fall damage is 1 (half heart) for each block fallen after the third. Thus falling 4 blocks causes 1 half heart damage, 2 (full heart) damage for 5 blocks, 3 (heart and a half) for 6 blocks and so forth. Assuming full health (but no Feather Falling or relevant status effects), a 23 block fall will be fatal (23 - 3 = 20 (Full Heart × 10) of damage).
>
> Mobs (other than chickens, ghasts, snow golems, blazes, magma cubes, iron golems, ocelots, bats and, presumably, the Ender dragon and wither) suffer fall damage as well.

A skeleton has 10 hearts, as well as zombies and creepers, so the fatal fall distance is 23 blocks for them.